# Assembly reference to Silverlight Toolkit not updating in a Windows Phone 7 project

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, assemblies, silverlight-toolkit

I made some changes in the Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone 7, more specifically, I made the
`internal static class Transitions`
public =>
`public static class Transitions`

and also the formerly private static method `GetStoryboard` method public:
`public static Storyboard GetStoryboard(string name)`

because I wanted to use Transitions.GetStoryboard to load a storyboard from the Toolkit and use that storyboard directly in my code. So, I rebuilt the Toolkit, and in my Phone App project, I first deleted the reference, then added the reference again (I've definitely selected the right .dll), but I don't get access to the Transition class. Visual Studio says: "'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Transitions' is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Somehow, the assembly reference is not updated. I've tried everything. I've deleted the Bin-folders, switched between Debug and Release build, etc. nothing did work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to delete the reference, clean your project and then point to the new dll. You can also try to set Copy Local = true.

Comment: Also, was the original reference a custom build of the toolkit? If not, double check the location of your original reference and the build output location of the newly generated library is the same (maybe you got the original from `root\bin`, for example, the pre-build, when a rebuild outputs to `root\project\bin\configuration`).

Comment: Cleaning didn't help. I have no folder `root\project\bin\configuration`, but i figured out, the .dll is also output to `root\project\obj\Release` and I tried that file, but it didn't work. The original reference was a custom build. Could the fact that the toolkit uses the namespace `Windows.Phone.Controls` cause such problems? The static method I want to access is `Windows.Phone.Controls.Transitions.GetStoryboard()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. The compiler is always picking the silverlight toolkit assembly from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Toolkit\Aug11

regardless that I have a newer version of the toolkit installed in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Toolkit\Oct11

or even if I set explicitly the reference path from the VS IDE. I solved the issue by modifying my .csproj with a HintPath

```
 <Reference Include="Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b772ad94eb9ca604,processorArchitecture=MSIL" >
 <HintPath>C:\WP_Development\WindowsPhoneToolkit\Source and Samples\Bin\Debug\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

This works, but I still can't understand why VS completely ignores the user defined path when the path is set from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: I ran into this exact problem also - I managed to fix it by uninstalling the older (August) version of the Silverlight toolkit in the control panel; this might not be an option depending on your circumstances though.